# Spark/Hive Hours Between Two Datetimes

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I would like to know how to precisely get the number of hours between 2 datetimes in spark.

There is a function called `datediff` which I could use to get the number of days and then convert to hours however this is less precise than I'd like

example of what I want modeled after `datediff`:

```
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2016-04-18 21:18:18','2016-04-19 19:15:00')], ['d1', 'd2'])
>>> df.select(hourdiff(df.d2, df.d1).alias('diff')).collect()
[Row(diff=22)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Scala: DateDiff of two columns by hour or minute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058016/spark-scala-datediff-of-two-columns-by-hour-or-minute)

Answer (score 0):

Try using UDF Here is the sample code, You can modify to UDF return what ever granularity as you want.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
def timediff_x():
    def _timediff_x(date1, date2):
        date11 = datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        date22 = datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return (date11 - date22).days
    return udf(_timediff_x, LongType())

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2016-04-18 21:18:18','2016-04-25 19:15:00')], ['d1', 'd2'])
df.select(timediff_x()(col("d2"), col("d1"))).show() 

+----------------------------+
|PythonUDF#_timediff_x(d2,d1)|
+----------------------------+
|                           6|
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are of type `TimestampType()`, you can use the answer at the following question:

[Spark Scala: DateDiff of two columns by hour or minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058016/)

However, if your columns are of type `StringType()`, you have an option that is easier than defining an UDF, using the built-in [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

diffCol = unix_timestamp(col('d1'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') -  unix_timestamp(col('d2'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2016-04-18 21:18:18','2016-04-19 19:15:00')], ['d1', 'd2'])
df2 = df.withColumn('diff_secs', diffCol)
```