# Spark SQL - How to find total number of transactions on an hourly basis

Tags: apache-spark-sql

For example, if i have a table with `transaction number` and `transaction date` [as `timestamp`] columns, how do i find out the total number of transactions on an `hourly basis`?

Is there any Spark sql functions available for this kind of range calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [from_unixtime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#from_unixtime(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) function.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = // your dataframe, assuming transaction_date is timestamp in seconds
df.select('transaction_number, hour(from_unixtime('transaction_date)) as 'hour)
      .groupBy('hour)
      .agg(count('transaction_number) as 'transactions)
```

Result:

```
+----+------------+
|hour|transactions|
+----+------------+
|  10|        1000|
|  12|        2000|
|  13|        3000|
|  14|        4000|
|  ..|        ....|
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm trying to give some pointer to approach, rather complete code, please see this

*[**Time Interval Literals** : 
Using interval literals, it is possible to perform subtraction or addition of an arbitrary amount of time from a date or timestamp value. This representation can be useful when you want to add or subtract a time period from a fixed point in time. For example, users can now easily express queries like 
**“Find all transactions that have happened during the past hour”**.
An interval literal is constructed using the following syntax:
[sql]INTERVAL value unit[/sql]](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/apache-spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights.html)*

---

Below is the way in python. you can modify the below example to match your requirement i.e transaction date start time, end time accordingly. instead of id in your case its transaction number.

```
# Import functions.
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
# Create a simple DataFrame.
data = [
  ("2015-01-01 23:59:59", "2015-01-02 00:01:02", 1),
  ("2015-01-02 23:00:00", "2015-01-02 23:59:59", 2),
  ("2015-01-02 22:59:58", "2015-01-02 23:59:59", 3)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["start_time", "end_time", "id"])
df = df.select(
  df.start_time.cast("timestamp").alias("start_time"),
  df.end_time.cast("timestamp").alias("end_time"),
  df.id)
# Get all records that have a start_time and end_time in the
# same day, and the difference between the end_time and start_time
# is less or equal to 1 hour.
condition = \
  (to_date(df.start_time) == to_date(df.end_time)) & \
  (df.start_time + expr("INTERVAL 1 HOUR") >= df.end_time)
df.filter(condition).show()
+———————+———————+—+
|start_time           |            end_time |id |
+———————+———————+—+
|2015-01-02 23:00:00.0|2015-01-02 23:59:59.0|2  |
+———————+———————+—+
```

using this method, you can apply group function to find total number of transactions in your case.

Above is python code, what about scala ?

[`expr` function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala) used above also available in scala as well

Also have a look at [spark-scala-datediff-of-two-columns-by-hour-or-minute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058395/647053) 
which describes below..

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val diff_secs_col = col("ts1").cast("long") - col("ts2").cast("long")
    val df2 = df1
      .withColumn( "diff_secs", diff_secs_col )
      .withColumn( "diff_mins", diff_secs_col / 60D )
      .withColumn( "diff_hrs",  diff_secs_col / 3600D )
      .withColumn( "diff_days", diff_secs_col / (24D * 3600D) )
```