# How to calculate the difference in time between 2 row in spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark-Scala technologies, as part of my learning, I am trying to find the time between two rows of same colum which consist of date and time together as seen below,

```
column1                     
1/1/2017  12:01:00 AM
1/1/2017  12:05:00 AM
```

So I want to get the time variation between two rows from row 1  and row 2 of column1 as both belongs to the same date.
Please let me know what would be the best method to achieve it?
Appreciate if anyone can help on this
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Scala: DateDiff of two columns by hour or minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058016/spark-scala-datediff-of-two-columns-by-hour-or-minute)

Comment: Can you add the datatype of column that shows time?

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast the column to timestamp and then do the diff calculation.
Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("1/01/2017 12:01:00 AM","1/1/2017 12:05:00 AM")).toDF("time1","time2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [time1: string, time2: string]

scala>  val df2 = df.withColumn("time1",to_timestamp('time1,"d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a")).withColumn("time2",to_timestamp('time2,"d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [time1: timestamp, time2: timestamp]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- time1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- time2: timestamp (nullable = true)

scala> df2.withColumn("diff_sec",unix_timestamp('time2)-unix_timestamp('time1)).withColumn("diff_min",'diff_sec/60).show(false)
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|time1              |time2              |diff_sec|diff_min|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|2017-01-01 00:01:00|2017-01-01 00:05:00|240     |4.0     |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+

scala>
```

**Update1:**

```
scala> val df = Seq(("1/01/2017 12:01:00 AM"),("1/1/2017 12:05:00 AM")).toDF("timex")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timex: string]

scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("timex",to_timestamp('timex,"d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timex: timestamp]

scala> df2.show
+-------------------+
|              timex|
+-------------------+
|2017-01-01 00:01:00|
|2017-01-01 00:05:00|
+-------------------+

scala>  val df3 = df2.alias("t1").join(df2.alias("t2"), $"t1.timex" =!= $"t2.timex", "leftOuter").toDF("time1","time2")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [time1: timestamp, time2: timestamp]

scala> df3.withColumn("diff_sec",unix_timestamp('time2)-unix_timestamp('time1)).withColumn("diff_min",'diff_sec/60).show(false)
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|time1              |time2              |diff_sec|diff_min|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|2017-01-01 00:01:00|2017-01-01 00:05:00|240     |4.0     |
|2017-01-01 00:05:00|2017-01-01 00:01:00|-240    |-4.0    |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+

scala> df3.withColumn("diff_sec",unix_timestamp('time2)-unix_timestamp('time1)).withColumn("diff_min",'diff_sec/60).show(1,false)
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|time1              |time2              |diff_sec|diff_min|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
|2017-01-01 00:01:00|2017-01-01 00:05:00|240     |4.0     |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+--------+
only showing top 1 row

scala>
```

Comment: the OP has changed the question..let me update the answer

Comment: I think this ans is only for 2 rows. =!= sign does not account for long time series. I recommend using < for time and self join based on a key.

Comment: @ShwetaKamble.. that is just to create 2 columns and 2 rows using self join..