# PySpark: Subtract Two Timestamp Columns and Give Back Difference in Minutes (Using F.datediff gives back only whole days)

Tags: python, date, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have the following sample dataframe.  The date_1 and date_2 columns have datatype of timestamp.

```
ID  date_1                      date_2                      date_diff
A   2019-01-09T01:25:00.000Z    2019-01-10T14:00:00.000Z    -1
B   2019-01-12T02:18:00.000Z    2019-01-12T17:00:00.000Z    0
```

I want to find the different between date_1 and date_2 in **minutes.**

When I use the code below, it gives me the date_diff column in whole integer values (days):

```
df = df.withColumn("date_diff", F.datediff(F.col('date_1'), F.col('date_2')))
```

But what I want is for date_diff to take into consideration the timestamp and give me minutes back.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Scala: DateDiff of two columns by hour or minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058016/spark-scala-datediff-of-two-columns-by-hour-or-minute)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just convert the timestamps to unix timestamps (seconds since epoch), compute the difference, and divide by 60.

For example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn(
    "date_diff_min", 
    (F.col("date_1").cast("long") - F.col("date_2").cast("long"))/60.
).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: how can i get the difference in hours when start and end date are different times in the  same day?
with the above answer i get 0 if difference in hours is < 24 hrs

Comment: It is not necessary to cast `date_1` and `date_2` to long. It is enough to cast once after the subtraction: `(F.col("date_1") - F.col("date_2")).cast("long")/60.`