# How do I do date diff in a spark sql environment?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with a creation date and an action date. I'd like to get the number number of minutes between the two dates. I looked at the docs and I'm having trouble finding a solution.

```
%sql
SELECT datediff(creation_dt, actions_dt)
FROM actions
limit 10
```

This gives me the number of days between the two dates. One record looks like

```
2019-07-31 23:55:22.0  |  2019-07-31 23:55:21 | 0
```

How can I get the number of minutes?

Comment: This question has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058016/spark-scala-datediff-of-two-columns-by-hour-or-minute

Comment: I don't know the name of using straight sql, but that hasn't been answered in this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, if you are using Spark or Pyspark then the withColumn method is best.

BUT

If you are using the SparkSQL environment then you could use the unix_timestamp() function to get what you need

```
select ((unix_timestamp('2019-09-09','yyyy-MM-dd') - unix_timestamp('2018-09-09','yyyy-MM-dd'))/60);
```

Swap the dates with your column names and define what your date pattern is as the parameters.

Both dates are converted into seconds and the difference is taken. We then divide by 60 to get the minutes.

```
525600.0
```