# Spark 3.0 timeStamp parsing doesn't work ever after passing the format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a issue I am facing with Spark 3.0, worked before without even specifying a format.
Now, I tried explicitly specifying the format, but it still doesn't work.
Here the input format, [image]

Here's the code I wrote,
[image]
Clearly, the format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm" should've worked, but it's not.
So I must be ignorant about a couple things here.

Answer (score 0):

Its not correct what you do since spark 3.0 there where major changes regarding the datetime formatting.

Here is a working example:

```
val df = Seq("12/21/2018 15:17").toDF("a")
df.select(to_timestamp($"a", "M/d/yyyy H:mm")).show()
```

Notice the capital H? that stands for hours 0-23

the lower case letter h stands for 1 - 12

reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but writing anyway.. I was experiencing the same problem with spark 2.4.6. Then I used SparkSQL and it worked very well.
I found the solutiın in this link:
[SparkSQL - Difference between two time stamps in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386256/sparksql-difference-between-two-time-stamps-in-minutes)

Example:

```
sqlContext.sql("select (bigint(to_timestamp(end_timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))-bigint(to_timestamp(start_timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')))/(60) as duration from table limit 2")
```